# How to efficiently iterate over pandas dataframe based on a columns value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, iteration

I have a `df` that has 3 columns, where the last column holds the code_name of a group.
This is the head of my `df`

```
    date         value      name
0   2015-02-26  0.033308    4332_1_2
1   2015-03-30  0.089551    4332_1_2
2   2015-04-15  0.518057    4332_1_2
3   2015-05-01  0.184956    4332_1_2
4   2015-05-17  0.291904    4332_1_2
```

I would like to iterate over this df based on the `name` column, meaning that in each iteration, only the rows that have the same name will be included. The method that I use is a "simple" loop:

```
for i in df['name'].unique():
    df_temp = df[df['name']==i].copy()
    do something with df_temp...
```

How can I improve the iteration?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: To find a better way to iterate over the df. It is not row or columns iteration, rather iteration over groups of rows based on a value of the columns name. The length of the groups is not equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a

```
df.groupby('name').apply(...)
```

You won't beat the performance of this with a raw loop.

Comment: The group by will group the other values such as the 'date' and the 'value', I need these values. For each group of rows, I need it to be in a dataframe structure because I need to do all kinds of things for each of these "mini" dataframes

Comment: That is literally what `groupby` does, don't try to reinvent things yourself. Create a custom loop for a pandas dataframe is not needed, especially not something trivial you want to do. I use `pandas` everyday, and maybe 1% of the time I have to loop over my dataframe.

Comment: So, let's say that for each "mini" dataframe I would like to apply 100 rows of code, I should write these 100 rows as a function and then pass it to apply?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Here are more details on how to write the function: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#flexible-apply